# Network Manager not changing connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Ubuntu 16.04, I've been using network manager for years to connect to a VPN. It stopped responding completely yesterday, and I can't get it to swap to the VPN connection now. I right click on the icon, select my connection, and nothing happens.

I tried removed all VPN connections (from /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/), rebooting, and setting up the VPN connection from scratch. Still same thing.

Comment: Any Errors from the Logs or when it tries to connect? My PIA Manager in Home contains my Logs, not sure what your using.

Comment: Its a manual VPN connection to a remote server running OpenVPN

Comment: I have even tried completely removing network manager and reinstalling, to no avail.

Comment: I am able to successfully swap connections via the command line `nmcli con up id` and the network manager icon actually changes!